# passing multiple arguments or object in (click)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Problem is to pass the object or multiple arguments from template to component and use them to add data to API.

task.service.ts

```
addTasks(task: Task): Observable<Task>{
 let headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
 return this.http.post(this.tasksUrl, {task}, options)
 .map(this.extractData)
 .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

task.component.ts

```
addTasks(task){
this.taskService.addTasks(task)
.subscribe(
  task => this.tasks.push(task),
  error => this.errorMessage = <any> error
);
```

}

Template Inputs:

```
<input #todoTime type="text" class="form-control">&nbsp;
<input #todoName type="text" class="form-control">
```

Template Button:

```
<button name="todoAdd" (click)="addTasks({name: todoName.value, time: todoTime.value}); todoName.value='',todoTime.value='' ">add</button>
```

Comment: right now what problem you are facing?
Question statement does not explain the error or problem.

Comment: Also I think this is possible "<button (click)="addTask(todoName)"></button>"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace the comman(,) with a semicolon when you are handling the `click` event for the button. That should work.

```
<button name="todoAdd" (click)="addTasks({name: todoName.value, time: todoTime.value}); todoName.value=''; todoTime.value='' ">add</button>
```

I have created this simple [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sACOMiRWRNPgciw7Eiiq?p=preview) that shows object is getting passed to `addTasks()` function.