# Angular 6: error while passing data to FireBase Collection

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

Im using Firebase for simple CRUD operations. But when trying to add a value to my collection, I get the following error: `CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: undefined`

The Model T.S (same as the database)

```
  export interface Users {
  id?: number,
  user?: string,
  recipe?: string
}
```

The Service

```
export class UsersService {

  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Users>;
  userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Users>;
  users: Observable<Users[]>;
  user: Observable<Users>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.usersCollection = afs.collection<Users>('recipes');
    this.users = this.usersCollection.valueChanges();



}

   addRecipe(recipe: Users) {
     this.usersCollection.add(recipe);
  }
```

Component TS

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  users:Users;
  constructor(private usersService:UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


addRecipe(recipe:Users){
  this.usersService.addRecipe(recipe);
}

}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <input class="form-control" type=text [(ngModel)]="users">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="addRecipe()">Recipe</button>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Could someone explain me why do I get this error and how to solve it?

EDIT: I pretent to add a new value to receipe, in this collection. The trhee documents above are empty[image]

Comment: recipe is undefined, its not pointing to anything

Comment: yes I know....Even if I capture the value of the input with and id, im trying to add a string to something that suppose to be an object, as I understand...

Comment: Try`(click) ="addRecipe({} )" ` and tell me if it works

Comment: Yes, it works, I get no errors and the log shows an object but empty. And in the console of Firebase I see nothing has been added Peter Haddad

Comment: No wait, I can see new collection entering the Database, but they are empty and they dont respect the model

Comment: Yes they are empty becuase there are no values inside of it. I put an empty object because your interface accepts optional parameters

Comment: Yes, but how am I going to add something? see my Edit

Comment: In the click method you need to add the data there like this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574243/passing-multiple-arguments-or-object-in-click

Comment: Great Peter, it works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is on the View. Data has to be passed on the HTML, as Peter suggested

```
      <input #inputName  type="text" class="form-control" >
 <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="addRecipe({user: inputName.value})">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using 'valueChanges()' function in 'this.users = this.usersCollection.valueChanges();'

try using:

```
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
     map(changes => {
      return changes.map(change => ({key: change.payload.key, ...change.payload.val()}));
     }))
```

.snapshotChanges will capture id and other metadata information of the collection.

Comment: I've tried that one but I get the error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentChangeAction<Users>[]´

Comment: I've added pipe() function, a feature of Angular 6. Also do you  have rxjs install and imported?

Comment: Yes, I do, actually I dont understand why map gets underlined

Comment: what version is the rxjs? please use the following import statement: import { map } from "rxjs/operators";   also restart your project to see if it helps

Comment: did like you told but now Observable gets underline, same as red